# MultiviewControl unable to display

Tags: asp.net

I have a menu with several buttons.

When i press the first button it sets the view to "visible".
Then a textbox + a button appear wihout any problem.

The problems lies where i wanne do the exact same thing for another button, the controls actually never show up.
Both are in 2 seperate views within 1 multiview control.

The multiview is located in a content page, and everything is triggered by pressing on a button that is located in the MasterPage.
In that button click event is a Response.Redirect that sends the page to the content page.

```
    string a = Request.QueryString["a"];
    string b = Request.QueryString["b"];

    if (a != "")
    {
        if (a == "addA")
        {
            MultiviewQuestions.SetActiveView(viewAddA);
        }
    }

    if (b != "")
    {
        if (b == "addB")
        {
            MultiviewQuestions.SetActiveView(viewAddB);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sets up a condition to have 2 active views which isn't allowed. Last in will always win. You need to specify which one you are setting if both a and b are set and true.

Comment: The thing is b is never true, altough the 2 controls are exactly the same. Or do i need to use some other cross page properties? The idea is from several buttons from a menu (mp) when it clicks another area opens (content place holder) which is located in a content page. And there all the websites "content" will be displayed.

Comment: What is the querystring that fails? And what result are you expecting from it?

Comment: The query string a only gets displayed (set active) when i press the button. So there should never be 2 active windows at once. The thing is with query string B it never goes "into" the if statement for some reason. Although everything is exactly the same, what kind of logical error might i be dealing with ?

Comment: @Tonz - it is case sensitive, it's possible you're sending B and looking for b.